# How to push changes from service to component in angular 5 when ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Tags: angular

I'm trying to optimize my angular app and try to use ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush.

I get a data from server in the services, and everything works when ChangeDetectionStrategy is don't specified.

Now it look like

```js
    export class Some{
      public name: string;
    }
    
    @Injectable()
    export class Service {
      public items: Some[] = [];

      constructor(http: HttpClient) {
          this.getModel();
        }
      getModel{
          this.http.get("some_url").subscribe((result: Some[])=>{
            this.items = result;
          }
        }
    }

    @Component({
        template: '<ul><li *ngFor="let item of service.items">{{item.name}}</li></ul>',
    })
    export class Component implements OnInit {        
        constructor(private service: Service) {
            
        }
    
        ngOnInit() {
        }
    }
```

How do push service data to component?

Comment: Please, share some code!

Comment: I added simple example

Answer (score 1):

Is better if you use a different approach in you component and service.

In your component, items should be an [`Observable`](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable):

```js
public items: Observable<Some[]>;
```

In the `ngOnInit` [lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), you will assign the the `getItems` method to the variable `items`.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this.service.getItems();
}
```

`getItems` should look like this:

```js
getItems(): Observable<Some[]> {
    return this.http.get("some_url");
}
```

Your view can now use the [`async` pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) to display the data:

```html
<ul><li *ngFor="let item of (items | async)">{{item.name}}</li></ul>
```